# Bluetooth Communication Message Send Process

Tags: android, bluetooth

i have used bluetooth chat application, in that i can successfully chat using bluetooth application.But what i need is that i need to send text message using bluetooth communication, i am expecting that my paired device may or may not have this bluetooth chat application, still it must receive all the text messages.

here in chat application, it need this application both sides same like messanger.

i need to commmunicate and send text message to any bluetooth device.

can anybody help me what should i do ?

Thank You